# Entity Framework DBContext navigation property loaded by different query?

Tags: entity-framework

I have two entities, user and messages. I like only to load messages and not the user a message belongs.

This usually works as I do not include the related entity in the linq query. But it doesn't work if I load the user separately with another query to get only a string from that user (the name).

I am using EF 6.1.0, POCO without proxy generation and WCF services to pass the data. The unwanted
navigation property value is then transferred accidentally.

```
var message = context.messages.FirstOrDefault(m => m.id == 123);

var user = contect.users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.id = 456);

var message_username_composition = new M_U_C{ m = message, username = user.name };

return message_username_composition;
```

In this situation I have the navigation property (user) of the message loaded even I do not like so.

Disabling LazyLoading doesn't help, only using a separate context solves the problem.

Is there a way other than using two contexts?

Is this by design?

I also do not like to manually set the navigation properties to null to fix this, because it may also
get forgotten, because one did not realize this behavior.

Comment: Why do you care if `message.User` is set?

Comment: This will be because of the way EF implements the [identity map pattern](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/identityMap.html). It knows that your message is related to the user with id 456 so it will automatically populate the property.

Comment: At the client side I change the user by the foreign key only, because I do not have all users loaded. Thus I have to set the navigation property to null, what may be causing errors. Also I just do not like to include an object graph into a service call result, if that is not required. I rather wonder why the navigation property get loaded by a different query. I have the feeling I cannot control the behavior in such a circumstance. Thus on the server side I may introduce inclusion accidentally by helper queries using the same context.

Comment: Dean: Can I change the behavior of that pattern? Or is the solution only a separate context?

Comment: haim770: Think about sensitive data, that may pass the service boundary accidentally!

Comment: @lollisoft, that's exactly what i was thinking, and that's why you don't send you entities over the wire, you use specific DTO/ViewModels.

Comment: Is `Message.User` marked as `virtual`?

Comment: Yes, it is virtual, but the code did not access the property, thus LazyLoading isn't the cause. Also I have this feature completely as a trial.

Comment: What @DeanWard mentioned is usually referred to as "Relationship Fix-Up" in EF.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to disable Lazy-Load and use `AsNoTracking()` as follows:

```
ctx.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
var message = context.messages.AsNoTracking().FirstOrDefault(m => m.id == 123);
```

Comment: I think another solution would be using a projection and select only those columns that are needed.